# Filtering Boxes showing all on load

Tags: javascript

I used some code from code pen to make some filtering boxes. It originally had a show all option that I took off. But the javascript is loading all of the options on load. What do I need to change in the JS to make it load the first option by default?
https://jsfiddle.net/zpzyy9ge/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *JavaScript* isn't showing those elements, they're simply displayed by default because they're on the page and you don't do anything to hide them.  (As a test, remove the JavaScript entirely and observe that they are still being displayed.)

You can hide them by default with a simple CSS rule, for example:

```
.box { display: none; }
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpzyy9ge/1/)

Comment: That only hides them. To only show the first option as by default like I was looking for, you just have to hide those specific elements